# a multiple choice question on monotone non-decreasing real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

let $f$ be a monotone non-decreasing real-valued function on $\mathbb{R}$ . Then
$1$. $\lim  _ {x \to a}f(x)$ exists at each point $a$.
$2$. If $a<b$ , then $\lim  _ {x \to a+}f(x) \le \lim  _ {x \to b-}f(x)$.
$3$. $f$ is an unbounded function.
$4$. The function $g(x)=e^{-f(x)}$ is a bounded function.

---

$2$ is looking obviously true.
but I need some counter example to disprove the others.can anyone help me please.thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

(1): $f(x) = 0$ on $(-\infty,0]$ and $f(x) = 1$ on $(0,\infty)$

(3): $f(x) = 1$.

(4): $f(x) = x$. Then $g(x) = e^{-x}$, so consider $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}g(x)$

Answer (score 2):

1: monotone does not necessarily mean it 's continuous

3: never said it was strictly monotone, could be constant

4: $g$ is strictly decreasing and has a lower bound never reached ($0$). It has an upper bound only if $f$ has a lower bound -> many counter examples

Answer (score 0):

For (1) and (3) consider $f(x)=\frac{n}{n+1}$, where $n$ is the least natural number such that $x\leq n$.